# What's the piece of music played at the 5min mark of episode 5 of Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

I'm asking about the classical piece played on the disc while Tsukiyama ponders over how to eat Kaneki.

I tried using Shazam to search, but unfortunately, it couldn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I'm watching the correct segment of *Tokyo Ghoul*, this is an extract from the first movement of Antonín Dvořák's [Symphony No. 9](https://youtu.be/jOofzffyDSA?t=113).